# How to solve this equation iteratively?

Tags: equation-solving

Please,

I need to solve iteratively by **Mathematica** this equation in order to get the solution $x^2$ at order $K^6$ :

$$x^2=\frac{a_1}{3}+\frac{a_2 K^2}{5x^2}+\frac{a_3 K^4}{7 x^4}+\frac{a_4 K^6}{9 x^6}$$
$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$ : arbitrary coefficients

```
 x^2=(Subscript[a, 4] K^6)/(9 x^6)+(Subscript[a, 3] K^4)/(7x^4)+(Subscript[a, 2] K^2)/(5 x^2)+Subscript[a, 1]/3
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Normally, iterative solutions are evaluated using numerical values of the parameters. Although it is possible in principle (e.g. formally using Newton's method and `NestList`), still it doesn't make much sense to calculate successive iterations *symbolically*. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes, but the solution may be written as a function of the arbitrary parameters `a1, a2, a3 and a4` too. I want to keep these parameters.

Comment: The equation is fourth order in `x^2`. Just use `Solve`

Comment: Sure, but then you will want to solve the equation *symbolically*, not iteratively. Try `Solve[x^2 == (a[4] k^6)/(9 x^6) + (a[3] k^4)/(7 x^4) + (a[2] k^2)/(5 x^2) + a[1]/3, x]` and gaze at the horror that are the symbolic solutions... Also, stay away from `Subscript` at the beginning; use indexed variables, i.e. `a[1]` instead of `Subscript[a, 1]`. Also stay away from uppercase variables; for instance, your `K` has a conflict with a built in symbol.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. I would like to obtain `x^2` in the form: `x^2=A+B K^2+C K^4+D K^6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve). First, it will be simpler to use a new variable `x2 = x^2`:

```
eqn = x2 == (Subscript[a, 4] K^6)/(9 x2^3) + (Subscript[a, 3] K^4)/(7x2^2) +
    (Subscript[a, 2] K^2)/(5 x2) + Subscript[a, 1]/3;
eqn //TeXForm
```

> $\text{x2}=\frac{a_4 K^6}{9 \text{x2}^3}+\frac{a_3 K^4}{7 \text{x2}^2}+\frac{a_2 K^2}{5
>    \text{x2}}+\frac{a_1}{3}$

At `K=0`, `x^2` is given by $a_1/3$, so the call to [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) is:

```
x2 /. First @ AsymptoticSolve[eqn, {x2, Subscript[a,1]/3}, {K, 0, 6}] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{3 \left(1134 a_2^3-2025 a_1 a_3 a_2+875 a_1^2 a_4\right) K^6}{875 a_1^5}+\frac{9
>    \left(25 a_1 a_3-21 a_2^2\right) K^4}{175 a_1^3}+\frac{3 a_2 K^2}{5 a_1}+\frac{a_1}{3}$

in agreement with my other answer.

Before you have access to M12, you can use [`CloudEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudEvaluate):

```
$VersionNumber
x2 /. CloudEvaluate @ First @ System`AsymptoticSolve[
    eqn,
    {x2, Subscript[a,1]/3},
    {K, 0, 6}
] //TeXForm
```

> 11.3
>
> $\frac{3 \left(1134 a_2^3-2025 a_1 a_3 a_2+875 a_1^2 a_4\right) K^6}{875 a_1^5}+\frac{9
>    \left(25 a_1 a_3-21 a_2^2\right) K^4}{175 a_1^3}+\frac{3 a_2 K^2}{5 a_1}+\frac{a_1}{3}$

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following? Here is your equation:

```
eqn =  x^2 == (Subscript[a, 4] K^6)/(9 x^6)+(Subscript[a, 3] K^4)/(7x^4) +
    (Subscript[a, 2] K^2)/(5 x^2)+Subscript[a, 1]/3;
eqn //TeXForm
```

> $x^2=\frac{a_4 K^6}{9 x^6}+\frac{a_3 K^4}{7 x^4}+\frac{a_2
>    K^2}{5 x^2}+\frac{a_1}{3}$

Construct a rule converting x to a series in K (still including x):

```
rule = x -> Sqrt[Series[eqn[[2]], {K, 0, 8}]];
rule //TeXForm
```

> $x\to \frac{\sqrt{a_1}}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{3} a_2 K^2}{10
>    x^2 \sqrt{a_1}}+\frac{\sqrt{a_1} \left(\frac{6 a_3}{7 x^4
>    a_1}-\frac{9 a_2^2}{50 x^4 a_1^2}\right) K^4}{4
>    \sqrt{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{a_1} \left(\frac{a_4}{x^6
>    a_1}-\frac{9 a_2 \left(\frac{6 a_3}{7 x^4 a_1}-\frac{9
>    a_2^2}{50 x^4 a_1^2}\right)}{20 x^2 a_1}\right) K^6}{6
>    \sqrt{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{a_1} \left(-\frac{3 a_3
>    \left(\frac{6 a_3}{7 x^4 a_1}-\frac{9 a_2^2}{50 x^4
>    a_1^2}\right)}{14 x^4 a_1}+\frac{a_2 a_4}{10 x^8
>    a_1^2}-\frac{a_2 \left(\frac{a_4}{x^6 a_1}-\frac{9 a_2
>    \left(\frac{6 a_3}{7 x^4 a_1}-\frac{9 a_2^2}{50 x^4
>    a_1^2}\right)}{20 x^2 a_1}\right)}{2 x^2 a_1}\right)
>    K^8}{8 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(K^9\right)$

Use this rule repeatedly until you get the result at the desired order (and free of x):

```
x^2 //. rule //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{a_1}{3}+\frac{3 a_2 K^2}{5 a_1}+\frac{9 \left(25 a_1
>    a_3-21 a_2^2\right) K^4}{175 a_1^3}+\frac{3 \left(1134
>    a_2^3-2025 a_1 a_3 a_2+875 a_1^2 a_4\right) K^6}{875
>    a_1^5}-\frac{27 \left(3969 a_2^4-9450 a_1 a_3 a_2^2+4900
>    a_1^2 a_4 a_2+2250 a_1^2 a_3^2\right) K^8}{6125
>    a_1^7}+O\left(K^9\right)$

Comment: thank you. But if I want `x^2` and not `x`?

Comment: I modified my answer to return x^2 instead.

Comment: It's what I am looking for. Thank you very well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little different approach that yields the same result:

```
eqn = x^2 == (Subscript[a, 4] K^6)/(9 x^6) + (Subscript[a, 
        3] K^4)/(7 x^4) + (Subscript[a, 2] K^2)/(5 x^2) + 
    Subscript[a, 1]/3 /. x -> Sqrt[x2]
```

First sub a series expression for `x2 (=x^2)` on both sides of the equation,
then take `Series` to the whole thing , finally require all the `K` coefficients to be zero..

```
vars = Table[b[i], {i, 0, 8}]
sol = Solve[
  CoefficientList[
    Normal@Series[ 
      eqn[[1]] - eqn[[2]] /. x2 -> Sum[b[i] K^i , {i, 0, 8}] , {K, 0, 
       8}], K] == 0, vars]

 Sum[b[i] K^i , {i, 0, 8}] /. sol
```

> same result

Comment: george2079, Thank you very well.